# NavigationController Issue on iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I am using  navigation bar on my application for reach next views in my iphone application.
in a stage of view  I want reach back my first view.How can i do it please give me suggestion.Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `popToRootViewControllerAnimated:` method that will remove all controllers from the stack and return the user to the first view controller.

See the [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW4).

Answer (score 1):

[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

This call will take you to the root of your view controllers

Comment: This call happens within the currently displayed view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use to go back to your previous view

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Hope it helps.